# Append a string to an array through strong parameters using << or Find_By_Sql in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to append a string value to two array columns ("good_product" & "bad_product") of a Postgresql model ("product.rb") using strong parameters with user input from form_for text fields. I have found two ways (<< & find_by_sql) to achieve this goal but can't get either to work.

For example, "Product 3" submitted through form_for input should be added to {"Product 1", "Product 2", _______ } (if other products exist in the array) OR an empty array (if no product added yet).

Model: product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :good_product, Array
  serialize :bad_product, Array
end
```

Controller: products.controller.rb

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
end

def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.good_product ||= []
  @product.bad_product ||= []
  @product.good_product << :good_product
  @product.bad_product << :bad_product
  redirect_to '/products'
end

private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:good_product => [], :bad_product => [])
  end
end
```

View: new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product, url: products_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :good_product, "Good Product" %>
  <%= f.text_field :good_product %>

  <%= f.label :bad_product, "Bad Product" %>
  <%= f.text_field :bad_product %>

  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Schema: schema.rb

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "good_product", default: [], array: true
  t.string   "bad_product", default: [], array: true
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "products", ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

Alternatively, instead of "<<", I tried this in the Controller:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  Product.find_by_sql(["UPDATE products SET good_product = array_append(good_product, '?') WHERE user_id = ?", @product.good_product, current_user]);
  Product.find_by_sql(["UPDATE products SET bad_product = array_append(bad_product, '?') WHERE user_id = ?", @product.bad_product, current_user]);
  redirect_to '/products'
end
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I think your problem is how you are referencing :good_product, try something like params[:product][:good_product] i.e change the line in the create method to be: `@product.good_product << params[:product][:good_product]`

Comment: "if other products exist in the array" -- since you're talking about a `create` action and you're using `Product.new`, you won't have an existing array because its a new product, correct? or am I missing something?

Comment: @eirikir You are correct. If other products exist in the array, the appropriate action should be edit/update - my bad!

Comment: @PaulFrench I tried your solution but the entered data don't get saved...

Comment: in your product params, can you try surrounding in brackets like:`params.require(:product).permit({:good_product => []}, {:bad_product => []})` ? Can you also check that it is being permitted by doing a `puts product_params` in your create method and seeing what it outputs?